# jqGrid: Resize column width on browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a table with many columns. I have a button, when pressed would expand the table to show all rows/ collapse the table to show only 5 rows. When its in the collapse mode I get a horizontal scroll bar on window resize. I want to get rid of it such that on window resize the column width changes keeping a minimum width. How can I achieve this?

I tried using `shrinkToFit`, but it just messes my table when I do an expand.